# Estimation of $\psi (n)$ in number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let 
$$\Lambda(n) = 
\begin{cases} \ln p &\quad \text{if } n = p^{\alpha} \text{ where } \alpha\geq 1 \\ 
0 &\quad \text{otherwise}  \end{cases}$$
and let 
$$
\psi(n)=\sum_{m=1}^{n} \Lambda(m)
$$
I need to prove that
$$
e^{\psi(2n+1)} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} (1-x)^n dx
$$
is a positive integer, and deduce
$$
\psi(2n+1) \geq 2n \ln 2
$$

Here is what I think:

I have already deduced that $e^{\psi (n)} = \text{lcm}(1,2,3,...,n) $. Thus
\begin{align*}
e^{\psi(2n+1)} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} (1-x)^n dx &= \text{lcm} ( 1,2,...,2n+1 ) \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n+1)!}\\
&= \text{lcm} ( 1,2,...,2n+1 ) \frac{n!}{2^n(2n+1)!!}
\end{align*}
Let $\{p_n\}$ be the sequence of all primes with monotone increasing order, and let $P=\{p_n\} \cap \{1,2,3,...,2n+1\} = \{p_1, p_2,...,p_k\}$. Let $\alpha_k = \max\{ m| p_k^m \in \{1,2,...,2n+1\} \}$. Then $\text{lcm}(1,2,3,...,2n+1)= \prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{\alpha_i}$. 
\begin{align*}
\text{lcm} ( 1,2,...,2n+1 ) \frac{n!}{2^n(2n+1)!!} &= \prod_{i=1}^{k} p_i^{\alpha_i} \frac{n!}{2^n(2n+1)!!}
\end{align*}
I cannot proceed any more. It seems like I need to consider two cases when $n$ is odd or even. But the process gets complicated. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
e^{\psi(2n+1)} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} (1-x)^n dx &= \text{lcm}(1,2,...,2n+1) \int_{0}^{1} x^n \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k x^k dx\\
&= \text{lcm}(1,2,...,2n+1) \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k \int_{0}^{1} x^{n+k} dx\\
&= \text{lcm}(1,2,...,2n+1) \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k \frac{1}{n+k+1}\\
&\in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align*}
$e^{\psi(2n+1)} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} (1-x)^n dx > 0$ is obvious.

Since 
\begin{align*}
e^{\psi(2n+1)} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n} (1-x)^n dx &= e^{\psi(2n+1)} \frac{n!}{2^n(2n+1)!!}\\
&\geq 1
\end{align*}
We have 
$$
e^{\psi(2n+1)} \geq \frac{2^n(2n+1)!!}{n!} \geq 2^{2n}
$$
which ends the proof.

I am so sorry that I work it out right after I asked this question. Thank you all! If my proof has any mistake, please let me know.